# Add three List<string> to WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to add three List to one datagrid. Each list should have its own row. The lists will only be created/changed once - this is during data import from a CSV file. I know how to add two lists to the datagrid by using the following code:

```
dtgCsvData.ItemsSource = time.Zip(temperature, (t, c) => new { time = t, temperature = c });
```

Where time and temperature are two of the three lists. The third and last list is named rate.

```
public List<string> temperature;
public List<string> time;
public List<string> rate;
```

However, I cannot see how I add the last list to the datagrid. How do I do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are all related, why are you even having three different lists? They should also live together. I mean create a class with all necessary properties.

```
public class TemperatureEntity
{
   public double Temperature {get; set;}
   public DateTime Time {get; set;}
   public string Rate{get; set;}//string or whatever type it is
}
```

All the three lists will now become a single List of `TemperatureEntity`

```
public List<TemperatureEntity> temperatures;
```

Then bind it to DataGrid.

```
dtgCsvData.ItemsSource = temperatures;
```

Comment: How do I add data to the TemperatureEntity class? Right now I use the following: ´temperature = new List<string>(reader.GetTemperature());´
                ´time = new List<string>(reader.GetTime());´
                ´rate = new List<string>(reader.GetRate());´

Comment: @MikaelKP What is your `reader`? you need to create new instance of `TemperatureEntity` and add it in the list. `temperatures.Add(new TemperatureEntity(){Temperature = temperatureValue, Time  = dateTime  })`

Answer (score 3):

you can use composite collection to bind all your lists to a data grid

like this -

```
<DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding temperature}" />
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding time}" />
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding rate}" />
                </CompositeCollection>
</DataGrid.ItemsSource>
```